# Changing a data binded label value to another text in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a asp gridview which displays the account transactions a user have made. As in transactions, there will be debit and credit of money.

Right now, my gridview displays either

```
Debit    Credit

$0          $100

$100      $0
```

and vice versa.

My question is, is there anyway to convert the 0 to a '-' so that it displays

```
Debit    Credit

--          $100

$100      -
```

instead??

My gridview is binded using SQLDataSource control. and the amount is a decimal type.

Or anybody can suggest what is the correct search term for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridview row databound event can be used to attain this. Please refer the link [GridView.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) for more details.

You can code like

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "$0")
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "-";
            if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "$0")
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "-";
        }

    }
```

Or you can use a for loop inside RowDataBound event if there are more columns to be formatted. Like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
 {
      if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "$0")
         e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "-";
 }
```

Comment: MANY THANKS! I tried both solutions that you gave me and another website gave me. Both of it works!